# Source a file into current shell using Ruby

Tags: ruby, shell

I have a Ruby script (say, `genrc.rb`) that generates a custom rc file (say, `~/.custom_rc`). How can I source this file in to the current shell by running the ruby script?

```
$ ruby genrc.rb
$ # commands from the ~/.custom_rc should be available here
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Ruby script (or any program, for that matter) cannot alter the shell that started it, so you’ll either have to run

```
source ~/.custom_rc
```

after running the script, or have the script also output the contents of the file to stdout, in which case you could do

```
source <(ruby genrc.rb)
```

or

```
eval "$(ruby genrc.rb)"
```

The script could also instead output the path to the written file, and you could do:

```
source $(ruby genrc.rb)
```

Comment: That's little unfortunate. But your suggested solutions will work, too. Thanks.

Comment: @codefx It’s really a good thing, though, keeps programs from unexpectedly changing your environment. Only shell built-ins (e.g. `eval` & `source`) have that power, everything else is a forked process.